# SGS 2, CM 12.1: getting a different recovery

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery

I have a Samsung Galaxy S 2 (or I9100). On this phone I have been running CWM with Cyanogenmod for quite a while.

Recently, I updated to Cyanogenmod 12.1. It was quite a hassle, but it works fine. The only real problem I have with it is that the recovery has changed. Now I have CM's own recovery, which misses a nand backup feature.
Since I have always used CWM, I would like that back. But maybe something else is fine too, I do not really know anyting about the world of recoveries.

This leads me to the folllowing main question: can I get CWM back with CM 12.1? And some side questions: is it even possible to just flash another recovery? Why was CWM removed from CM 12.1? Is there another alternative flash? How would it work, flashing a new recovery?

Comment: Not posting an answer as I cannot tell for CM12: I had a similar experience with CM10.2 replacing my CWM by TWRP, so I "googled" that back then (to see whether that's normal). Yes, you can replace the recovery separately – but of course you must pick one matching your device. What I'm not sure about is whether CM12 requires a specific minimum version – I vaguely remember something like that. Flashing that recovery usually works via "apply update from sd card" in recovery, which CM recovery has.

Comment: Go into Developer options and uncheck "Update/Enable Cyanogen Recovery". Now flash any of your compatible recovery, be it CWM or TWRP or Philz. As for "Why was CWM removed from CM 12.1?" -- it happened sometime ago and not only for 12.1 release. Visit a search engine with your question and you would know for sure. For "How would it work, flashing a new recovery?" -- it's also available very easily on web. Start searching and if you get stuck somewhere, ask us.